# How do I make corners rounded only on the top part of the border in css?

Tags: html, css

In my site I need to make a div have rounded corners only on the top corners.  But I don't know how to do this. Can someone help me?

Comment: What have you tried when attempting to set the [`border-radius`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius)?

Comment: It is confusing as to what constitutes a real question.  If this is not a real question then what is?

Comment: Even in the first revision of this question it was easy enough to see what was being asked.  I agree, this shouldn't have been closed.

Comment: Why was this question closed? The reason given was that it is not a real question because it is difficult to understand but it is 100% obvious what is being asked. The only conclusion that I can come to is, the person who closed it is not a programmer or a web developer but I think this question would be easy to understand even if the person doesn't know how to use a computer. This question should not be closed.

Comment: Please note that this is a question and answer site, not a
code writing service. If you [edit] your question to
describe what you have tried so far and where you are stuck,
then we can try to help with specific problems. You should
also read [ask].

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Brendan's answer is correct, but to get it to render in more browsers, you should use this:

```
-moz-border-radius: 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
```

Comment: border-radius is pretty much standardized already. It would work in all new browsers without a vendor prefix.

Comment: You cannot assume everyone is using new browsers however.  Better to cover your bases.

Comment: Agreed - but you might as well drop the `-moz-` now - it's been long enough

Comment: You could use AutoPrefixer too https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer

Comment: http://shouldiprefix.com/#border-radius

Answer (score 43):

```
border-top-left-radius: 3px;
border-top-right-radius: 3px;
```

Comment: Note: the accepted answer will put rounded corners on the top but will also change the bottom corners to be square.

Answer (score 32):

The other answers are correct but there is the shorthand solution:

```
border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
```

which will round only the top corners and leave the bottom ones alone. The order of the values is clockwise - top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/9sXWf/

Comment: I'm sure you know how to format your code properly, as well as hopefully provide a complete example?

Comment: Umm.. okay, sure. Added example and reformatted answer.